# Hiding Derived Properties Not Working? C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I have a custom control, call it `ctrlFoo`, that derives from `System.Web.UI.Control`.

When this custom control is instantiated I can see all `System.Web.UI.Control`'s public properties which is abit annoying in intellisense, as there are so many of them.

Inside `ctrlFoo` i've tried

```
private new string SkinID { get; set; }
```

But I can still see this property in the initialised instance of `ctrlFoo`.

Can anyone offer any other suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want to hide functions that your class has perfectly valid access to? If they aren't applicable, perhaps it's worth considering whether or not you inherited from the right class...?

Comment: @Kiley Naro System.Web.UI.Control is the base class.

Comment: I guess it was only a matter of time until I heard someone call IntelliSense "annoying". Let me tell you how IntelliSense worked back in 1990...

Comment: @Jon Please point out where I called Intellisense annoying and I will correct it.

Comment: @maxp: Since you ask, *"which is abit **annoying** in intellisense, as there are so many of them"*. But you don't really have to edit it, much less correct a mistake that does not exist (annoyance is subjective).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the point of inheriting from `Control`. If `ctrlFoo` really *is a* `Control`, then you shouldn't be hiding properties that `Control`s have. `Control` has a `SkinID`, so `ctrlFoo` should have a `SkinID` too.

If you don't like what appears in Intellisense, then change your Intellisense settings (I've never heard anyone complain about IntelliSense before).

Answer (score 0):

You can still see it because you see the `System.Web.UI.Control.SkinID`, which is public.

You may hide that property by making access modifiers `private` for `get` and `set` accessors, but the base property must be virtual or abstract to be overriden.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide inherited properties.  This would violate the Liskov substitution principle.